# How Do I Create/Configure Spring Actuator for Multiple Datasources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project with multiple datasources and also implements spring actuator. When I access /health I get the following:

```
{"status":"DOWN"}
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. What is down? Also, why is database health missing? I'm assuming it's because my datasource prefix forks from the default.

How do I configure actuator /health to display both datasource health statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, health endpoint check more than one indicator. You only have `{"status":"DOWN"}` because by default spring boot application are secure.

You can modify your `application.properties` with

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

to show all health indicators.

You can find all auto-configured health indicators in this page : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators

And also, you can write your own health indicator by implementing `HealthIndicator`.

```
 @Component
 public class MyHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
       int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
       if (errorCode != 0) {
         return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
       }
       return Health.up().build();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, cool, but how do I add my `HealthIndicator` info to the /health endpoint?

Comment: you don't need to add it explicitly. Spring will scan your indicator and add it automatically.

Comment: Ok, I guess that is my confusion part. I know my custom indicator is called, but /health endpoint still says `{"status":"DOWN"}` I expected more information regarding my indicator and not just "status"

Comment: I got it. It was restrictions to `management.security.enabled` The custom indicator wasn't even necessary.

Comment: This is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Since this actuator is now deprecated (maybe this will be helpful for someone), you can use this:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```